# Текстурирование произвольной геометрии

Tags: three.js

Задача: в массив пушится n-ое количество точек, по которым создаётся произвольная геометрия, после её отрисовки накладывается геометрия.
Используя ConvexGeometry для этого, я столкнулся с проблемой наложения текстур.

К примеру: к геометрии состоящей из 5-ти вершин применяется текстура, в результате чего: [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

вопрос - как избежать искривления текстур, т.к. судя по всему здесь что-то с UV - то как настроить UV для данной геометрии

Comment: Хорошо. А вопрос в чем состоит?

Comment: @Kromster исправил вопрос*

Comment: Видимо UV выходят за пределы единичного квадрата. В железе указана тянуть краевые пиксели (константная экстраполяция). Какой результат вам нужен?

Comment: @StanislavVolodarskiy нужно чтобы текстура отображалась как на стандартном Plane, а не единичным квадратом

Comment: Это то что вы видите сейчас: "The default is THREE.ClampToEdgeWrapping, where the edge is clamped to the outer edge texels. The other two choices are THREE.RepeatWrapping and THREE.MirroredRepeatWrapping. See the texture constants page for details."

Comment: Чтобы растянуть текстуру нужно линейно отобразить UV в единичный квадрат.

Comment: @StanislavVolodarskiy честно признать, знал бы я как это сделать...

Comment: Пока поделите все UV на 10.

Comment: @StanislavVolodarskiy это какие-то махинации надо проделать с mesh?

Comment: Да, все UV на меше надо отскалировать и сместить так чтобы они оказались внутри единичного квадрата. Тогда текстура накроет одним листом всю вашу геометрию.

Comment: Если хотите помощи в виде кода и объяснений, поместите в вопрос минимальный рабочий пример. Пока всё на уровне лечения по фотографии.

Comment: @Leobuildru Посмотри ответ на форуме про то, как пересчитать UV у геометрии: https://discourse.threejs.org/t/texturing-polyhedron-geometry/50103

Answer (score -1):

ответ был получен на форуме three.js:
https://discourse.threejs.org/t/texturing-polyhedron-geometry/50103/3

проблема заключалась в wrapS и wrapT, они банально не задавались на повторение ¯_(ヅ)_/¯